# does every gem have its own rake?

Tags: ruby, rake, ruby-1.9.2, rhodes

Does every gem have its own rake? Because I was doing android development and I created app using the z$ rhogen app z. and then i did $rake run:android and the android emulator came up. But when I create an app using `$rhosync app <appname>` then migrate to the root of the app folder and do `$rake:dtach install` then the rake uses my older version of Ruby 1.8 where as my new and active Ruby version is Ruby 1.9.2.  I dont know where to change the config file of the app or gem I am not sure to make Ruby 1.9.2 as my default ruby when I do `$rake dtach:install`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex said, rake tasks are not needed in order to have a gem.

What environment are you working on? RVM is a nice way to manage you ruby environments and manage multiple versions of ruby on unix based systems (OS X/ubuntu/debian). Have a look here http://beginrescueend.com/

Comment: Yeah I made my default ruby version as 1.9.2 using rvm. but the problem  now is the error ~/RhodesDen/storemanager-server$ sudo rake dtach:install --trace
/home/uday/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:314:in `bin_path': can't find gem rake ([">= 0"]) with executable rake (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
 from /usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'

Answer (score 0):

No, not all gems have rake tasks.